# home networking create vlans or subnets on router?

Tags: router, wireless-router, home-networking, subnet, vlan

I have a [C20 TP-link home router](https://www.tp-link.com/us/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c20/) and I was interested in subnetting (is the same thing as a vLAN?) my home network...is it possible isolate via subnetting (vLAN?) everything that is hard wired into the router Vs anything wireless? This would create added security right between wireless devices and anything plugged in hard wired?

Looking at this [other post](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/887/) from TP-link website it seems like this is possible on a more powerful device. Can I do this with mine? This is what my menu looks like below or could a solution be just using "Guest Network" for all home Wi-Fi devices that don't do any online banking or financial transactions? Thanks for any tips not a lot of wisdom here...

[image]

Comment: VLAN is not for the home users at the first place. Companies use it when really need to separate traffic. For instance office network from production network. For test purpose of course you can configure it. Be sure that all device connects to your VLAN capable device otherwise will not get the packets (VLAN requires hw. support).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The
[Archer C20 V5 User Guide](https://www.tp-link.com/us/user-guides/Archer-C20_V5/chapter-4-configure-the-router-as-a-standard-wireless-router#ug-sub-title-6)
describes in "Chapter 4 Configure the Router", sub-section
"6.5. Wireless Advanced", an option that might help:

> Enable Client Isolation - This function isolates all connected wireless stations so that wireless stations cannot access each other through WLAN.

[image]

Your router doesn't seem to support VLANs.

Comment: Thank you for your posted answer